# Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted, while deploying contract with web3js

Tags: web3js, polygon, deploy

I maintain a web3 application, for each customer I deploy a smart-contract through the application. The contract was good and I were able to deploy it on polygon, but it isn't comply with the ERC721 standard so I decided to upgrade (for the new customers) the code of the contract to comply with the ERC721 standard.

I decided (to simplify) to generate a single file with the code of all smart-contracts and interfaces taken by OpenZeppelin: my contract is about 2000 lines of code now.

I tested the contract with remix (web version) through mumbai blockchain and all goes well, no errors and each public functions work good. I copied the code of the new smart-contract on the repository of my project and I running it to test everything ...bam: web3js returned the error [Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted] without further info:

```
ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
 at Web3RequestManager._isReverted (file:///app/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:326:19)
 at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (file:///app/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:272:42)
 at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (file:///app/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:171:29)
 at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
 at fulfilled (file:///app/node_modules/web3-core/lib/esm/web3_request_manager.js:20:58)
 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

```json
{
    "innerError": {
        "innerError": null,
        "name": "Eip838ExecutionError",
        "code": -32000,
        "receipt": null,
        "data": null
    },
    "name": "ContractExecutionError",
    "code": 310,
    "receipt": null
}
```

If I replace the new code with the old code, everything goes well but I can deploy the new code with Remix without errors. Anyone can help me to understand which is my problem?

This is the smart-contract:
https://github.com/colauttilorenzo/CertifieToken/blob/main/CertifieToken.sol

and this is the deploy job (written in typescript):

```typescript
      const privatekey = await this.get_privatekey(mnemonic);
      const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privatekey);
      web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);

      const contract_to_be_deploy: any = new web3.eth.Contract(ctrc.abi as any);
      const deployTx = contract_to_be_deploy.deploy({ data: ctrc.bytecode as string, arguments: [
        this.company.wallet.address,
        data.certificate_name,
        data.certificate_symbol,
        data.metadata,
        -1
      ]});
      const deployTxData = deployTx.encodeABI();
      const gas: bigint = await deployTx.estimateGas();
      const nonce: bigint = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(signer.address);
      const gasPrice: bigint = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
      const rawTransaction = {
        from: signer.address,
        gas: gas > 3000000 ? gas : 3000000,
        gasPrice,
        data: deployTxData,
        nonce,
      };

      await web3.eth
        .sendTransaction(rawTransaction)
        .on('transactionHash', (hash: string) => {
          console.log('[smart contract deployed]', `${(this.application.provider.blockExplorerUrls || [])[0]}/tx/${hash}`);
        })
```

Thanks so much to everyone!